# XML-RPC not working and using functions usage in Bugzilla

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, bugzilla

I am writing a program to extract a comment from the bug. So first using XML-RPC I am trying to connect to Bugzilla and do it via

putting http://bugzilla.yourdomainname.com/xmlrcp.cgi

So here is my code....

```
setCookieJar();
    $oClient->setHttpClient($oHttpClient);

    $aResponse = $oClient->call('User.login', array(array(
    'login'=>'username',
    'password' => 'password',
        'remember' => 1
    )));
    //Log into bugzilla.


    function getInfoBug(int $bugno)
    {
    $aResponse = $oClient->call('Bug.get($bugno)');
    //this would just return bug no.
    $aResponse = $oClient->call('Bug.get( ids => [$bugno], include_fields => [\'id\', \'comments\'] )');
    //Getting info about bugs.
    $final = $Client->call('Bug.get(comments($aResponse)');
    //
    return $final;
   }

    $bug = 1379;

    echo $answer = getInfoBug($bug);
?>
```

So actually am not really sure if I am calling the function correctly from the Buzilla API and another problem that is coming is that

> Warning: require_once(Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\Aakash\bugzilla.php on line 6
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php' (include_path='/usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php') in C:\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\Aakash\bugzilla.php on line 6

So am not really sure what is happening. Am just a beginner in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see that Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php exists in the PHP include directory and that the permissions are set correctly for the user that your PHP script is being runas.